# How to set two backgrounds?

Tags: backgrounds, preamble

`background` package defines a background with absolute position in preamble, but how to set two independent backgrounds at different positions? Consider we have two backgrounds as

```
\SetBgColor{red}
\SetBgPosition{0,0}
\SetBgContents{content1}

\SetBgColor{blue}
\SetBgPosition{1cm,5cm}
\SetBgContents{content2}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The background material can be pretty much anything; in particular, it can be a `tikzpicture` environment, and inside this environment you can use two independent `\node`s to place your material:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{background}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\SetBgAngle{0}
\SetBgScale{3}
\SetBgOpacity{1}
\SetBgContents{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node[text=red] at (0,0) {content1};
\node[text=blue] at (2,-2) {content2};
\end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-10]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This method does not apply to simple text, but resolved my problem as I'm using tikz too. I wanna take the chance to thank you for your excellent package. It's very flexible, and I am using it for various purposes. This is the reason that I need more than one :)

Comment: Just for sake of clarification! Your codes did not work for me until setting a value for `SetBgPosition`.