# Draft watermark in both margins using the background package

Tags: tikz-pgf, backgrounds, watermark

I tried to adapt [How to add “DRAFT” along the left/right margin?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/231332/3406) to have symmetrical "DRAFT"s along both margins, one running down the right margin, and one running down the left margin. Trying the obvious thing of using `\backgroundsetup` twice doesn't work - only the second one is printed.

I tried an approach based on [How do you add multiple watermarks?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/134795/3406), but had trouble getting it to work.

Here is my code based on the approach described in 
[How to set two backgrounds?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/52638/3406):

I tried replacing `(0,0)` with `current page.east`, but the watermark disappeared. How do I get something similar to the example in
[How to set two backgrounds?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/52638/3406)?

I'm open to other approaches to this.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{background}

\backgroundsetup{
  angle=0,
  opacity=1,
  scale=3,
  contents={%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node[text=gray,rotate=-90,anchor=east, yshift=5mm] at (0,0) {DRAFT1};
\node[text=gray,rotate=90,anchor=west, yshift=5mm] at (0,0) {DRAFT2};
\end{tikzpicture}}
}

\begin{document}
  \lipsum
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the *tikzpagenodes* package to easily access the textarea as a node.

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{background}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\backgroundsetup%
{   angle=0,
    opacity=1,
    scale=1,
    contents=%
    {   \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay, scale=3]
            \fontsize{100}{120}\selectfont
            \node[text=gray!50!red,rotate=90, above=1cm] at (current page text area.west) {DRAFT 1};
            \node[text=gray!50!blue,rotate=-90, above=1cm] at (current page text area.east) {DRAFT 2};          
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum \lipsum

\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

---

**Edit 1:** You can also place the "Draft" watermarks automatically in the middle of the margin. I assume you want them to be centered at the text area rather than the page area. While for most cases it will be almost the same, I constructed an extreme case to show the differences.

Here, the top margin is only 5mm while the bottom margin is 90mm. This leads to `current page.west` (orange dot) being at a much lower position than `current page text area.west` (green dot). So if one simply computes the midpoint via the *calc* library's `(A)!0.5!(B)` one arrives at a quite low postition (blue dot). To work around that, one can use a special syntax:

> In general, the meaning of (p |- q) is “the intersection of a vertical line through p and a horizontal line through q.”

With this syntax, one can compute the position of a coordinate that runs vertically through `current page.west` and horizontally through `current page text area.west` (black dot). Then one can use the midpoint of this position and `current page text area.west` to find the final position where the watermark will be placed (red dot).

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[inner=30mm, outer=50mm, top=5mm, bottom=90mm, twoside]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usepackage{background}

% for coordinate computations
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

% allows for arbitrarily large font sizes
\usepackage{lmodern}

% dummy text
\usepackage{lipsum}

\backgroundsetup%
{   angle=0,
    opacity=1,
    scale=1,
    color=black,
    contents=%
    {   \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
            \fontsize{80}{108}\selectfont
            % nodes for illustration purposes
            \node[circle,minimum width=4mm,fill=green] (PTAW) at (current page text area.west) {};
            \node[circle,minimum width=4mm,fill=orange] (PW) at (current page.west) {};         
            \node[circle,minimum width=4mm,fill=red] (BMW) at ($(current page text area.west -| current page.west)!0.5!(current page text area.west)$) {};
            \node[circle,minimum width=4mm,fill=blue] (GMW) at ($(current page.west)!0.5!(current page text area.west)$) {};
            \node[circle,minimum width=4mm,fill=black] (GW) at (current page text area.west -| current page.west) {};
            % the watermarks
            %\node[text=gray,rotate=90] at ($(current page text area.west -| current page.west)!0.5!(current page text area.west)$) {DRAFT 1};
            \node[text=gray,rotate=-90] at ($(current page text area.east -| current page.east)!0.5!(current page text area.east)$) {DRAFT 2};          
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum \lipsum

\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: That looks good, thanks. Do you understand why my earlier attempt was not working? I.e. why `current page.east` does not work, for example?

Comment: @FaheemMitha: In your `(0,0)` approach, the "Draft" is placed at the center of the page, as expected. But as you use `scale=3`, the positions of the nodes are shifted, so they are far outside your page. Try with `scale=1` and plae "Draft1" `west`  and "Draft2" `east`.

Comment: @FaheemMitha: Also, you made me realize how idiotic this whole `(north east)!0.5!(south east)` business is, if one can just use `(east)`. D'oh! I updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: Well, `current page.east` does not work, but your `current page text area.east` does. I'm not sure what the differences between those are.

Comment: Actually, it would nice to have an automated way to have the text located at the midpoint of the margin width, rather than having to adjust it manually.

Comment: @FaheemMitha: The [manual of _tikzpagenodes_](http://mirror.unicorncloud.org/CTAN/graphics/pgf/contrib/tikzpagenodes/tikzpagenodes.pdf) has a nice illustration on the second page showing that `current page` is really the whole page, while `current page text area` is only the text area. So if you try to position something outside of the `current page` it will obviousely not show up. In my first example, change the `above` to `below` to work with `current page`.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, Tom. I didn't quite register that `tikzpagenode`  was a separate package. Would using `current page marginpar area` be a possible alternative? I.e. putting the text in the center of that area? I'll experiment.

Comment: And yes, I think it makes sense for the watermarks to be centered at the text area rather than the page area.