Force exact location of text as background without affecting other text
I have the following code:
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[a4paper,left={1in}, right={1in}, top={1in}, bottom={1in}]{geometry}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary {calc}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[rectangle, draw=none, minimum size=1pt] at 
                   (0, -26.5) {TST TESTTES TESTTESTTEST};
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}

What I am trying to do is to force a text at exactly the bottom left corner of the first page. But because the first page is full, some text on it moves to the second page.
How can I force this text as if it was a background so that no other text is shifted?

normally you would just define a page style and place the text in the footer eg with fancyhdr package

the footer is placed at a fixed known position so you can place text anywhere on the page from that known start.

Thanks. I just simplified my question.

You don't need TikZ.
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[
  a4paper,
  left=1in,
  right=1in,
  top=1in,
  bottom=1in,
]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\AddToHookNext{shipout/background}{%
  \put(0,-\paperheight){\raisebox{\depth}{\strut TST TESTTES TESTTESTTESTy}}%
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-10]

\end{document}



\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[a4paper, left={1in}, right={1in}, top={1in}, bottom={1in}]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz, tikzpagenodes}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
\node[anchor=south west, inner sep=0pt] at (current page.south west) {TST TESTTES TESTTESTTEST};
\end{tikzpicture}%
%
\lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}



Thanks. I just found a proper answer here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52635/how-to-set-two-backgrounds (use it as background)
